# Unreal Engine кнопка нажимается только 1 раз. Что делать?

Tags: unreal-engine-4

Я использую 3d widget в своем проекте, на виджете есть три кнопки (играть, настройки, выход), но кнопка настройки не используется поэтому при нажатии на нее ничего не произойдёт, так вот я заметил, что если нажать на такую кнопку то на нажатие на остальные кнопки не будет срабатывать они полностью перестают работать. Я не знаю, что с этим делать я уже в настройках кнопки изменил метод нажатия на "Precise click", но это не помогло, ещё странный момент, что у кнопок срабатывает только событие OnPressed. Можно сказать так убери пустую кнопку настройки, но нет я ради интереса сделал на кнопку настройки widget switcher который будет переносить в настройки где есть кнопка выхода из настроек, но после нажатия на кнопку настройки кнопка выхода назад в меню перестает так же работать.

Использую unreal engine 4.27

Answer (score 0):

Помогло включение в widget -> interaction -> Receive Harware Input
[image: Способ исправить]